# Angular 2, TypeScript & ui-router - How to get state params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, angular-ui-router

Hey everyone I was wondering how to get the state params from a state using Angular 2, TypeScript & ui-router. I tried reviewing the new docs but they don't seem to have much documentation for ng2 ui-router.

**Below I have added my component.ts for reference. Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import {UIRouter} from 'ui-router-ng2/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'Detail',
  template: require('./detail.html'),
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})

export class Detail {
  constructor(private uiRouter:UIRouter) {
    console.log('uiRouter ', this.uiRouter.globals.params);
  }
}
```

**In Angular 1 I would do this as follows:**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
  .module('private')
  .controller('Controller', Controller);

  function Controller($state) {
    var vm = this;
    console.log($state.params.studentID);
  }
})();
```

**Again any advice would be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I was able to resolve the state param issue I was having by doing the following:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import {UIROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'ui-router-ng2';
import {UIRouter} from 'ui-router-ng2/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'Detail',
  template: require('./detail.html'),
  directives: [UIROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})

export class Detail {
    public detailParam: any;

    constructor(private uiRouter:UIRouter) {
      this.detailParam = this.uiRouter.globals.params;
      console.log('state params: ', this.detailParam);
  }
}
```

**But after a little more research I found better documentation on ui-router for Angular 2 here:** https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/

**Looks like the correct way of dealing with state params is with**

```
import {Transition} from "ui-router-ng2"
```

**And using**

```
trans.params().detailID
```

I was not able to get the trans.params() to work at this particular moment but at least I found a temporary solution and better documentation to find the proper solution.

Comment: Now even I have same doubt, If u get proper solution please comment that.

Answer (score 1):

please see my answer about how you can use *Transition* (as was mentioned by Galactic Ranger) in order to get stae parameters: [How to read $stateParms value in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41377832/how-to-read-stateparms-value-in-angular2/41388046#41388046)