# How to read $stateParms value in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

Using Ui-Router
In Angular1 The  stateparam value is coming using $state.params

How to do the same thing in ANgular2

I tried like this **this._uiRouter.globals.params.id**

it's working, But its not a proper solution, even I am using webstrome editor,
the editor also showing error like **TS2339 Property id does not exits on typeStateParams**,

Please help me do proper way

Comment: have you checked `params` from `this._uiRouter.stateService.params` ?

Comment: yes , When I console it I am getting one object StateParams {id:'1'}

Comment: if your required params coming in it you can use `this._uiRouter.stateService.params` to get your params value

Comment: If I print this._uiRouter.globals.params.StatePams.id it gives undefined

Comment: Ya I am getting that, Is there any other proper way

Comment: i don't know if there is any other way

Comment: What do you mean an other proper way ?

Answer (score 3):

you can get state parameters from the *Transition* exportable object while configuring URL state:

```
import {Transition} from "ui-router-ng2";
...
export const personState = {
  name: 'person',
  url: '/people/:personId',
  component: Person,
  resolve: [
    { 
      token: 'stateParams', 
      deps: [Transition],
      resolveFn: (trans) => trans.params()
    }
  ]
};
```

then in you component code:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {UIROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Transition} from 'ui-router-ng2';

@Component({  
  directives: [UIROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `
    <h2>stateParams</h2>
    <pre>{{ stateParams | json }}</pre>
`})

export class Person implements OnInit { 
  @Input() stateParams;

  ngOnInit() {
    // here you will have all passed state params
    console.log(this.stateParams);
  }

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

modified plunker from the https://ui-router.github.io/tutorial/ng2/hellosolarsystem#live-demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/IVGx0p9lQr1yKqgwZT4X

pay attention to 2 files:

1. state.ts
2. components/person.ts

Comment: UIRouter_DIRECTIVE declaration in @component is not accessible.

Comment: if you mean UIROUTER_DIRECTIVES, then they are imported from ui-router-ng2 module: import {UIROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Transition} from 'ui-router-ng2 (I updated my answer with 2 imports)'; Please check working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/IVGx0p9lQr1yKqgwZT4X?p=preview, press "People" link and then click on any person - state params are consol.logged and printed on screen.

Answer (score 2):

These days it's simpeler. In your constructor inject this:

```
import {StateService} from '@uirouter/core';

private stateService: StateService
```

You can then access the params via this variable:

```
this.stateService.params
```

Comment: I think this is a much cleaner solution! Thanks :)